# java verify error while processing XSLT transform for FPML

Tags: xml, xslt, java-7

I am transforming FPML into canonical XML using X-S-L-T transformation using xslt 1.0 with java 1.7 TransformerFactory.

Everything is working fine with a 2000+ lines of X-S-L-T with multiple  when   and   for-each  tags, but it crashed once I added few more lines of code.  When I removed some lines of code it started working fine again. 
So I want to know that is there any limits on how many lines of code can be used in a XSLT file.

Comment: Exception trace is below - 
    
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: FPML, method: template$dot$2$outline$0 signature: (LFPML$0;)V) Register 6 contains wrong type
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)

Comment: For help : please refer below link -
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8169112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely looks like a bug in the XSLT processor. It may or may not be because of the size of your XSLT code. You could try breaking up your XSLT code into smaller units (templates) to see if that solves the problem. Or you could look to see if there is a way to disable XSLTC's byte code generation, which is where the failure is occurring (Xalan has both interpreted and compiled modes of execution).

You could also of course switch to Saxon - on the Java platform there's really no reason to be using a version of XSLT that is now nearly 20 years old, and even with quite simple requirements you would get considerable productivity benefits from the new features in XSLT 2.0 and 3.0.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for your helpful words. But the problem is I am working on a project which itself is 12 + year old and many things need old jdk and other jar stuff.
I'll try to reduce the code by code re-usability and will see if it works. However it is very tough as FPML maps to different variety of financial products and we need to process it based on multiple conditions in different products. Any suggestions where I should report this bug?

Comment: Also as there are other XSLT files using the 1.0 version and project is not getting migrated to 2.0 or higher anytime sooner, I found myself bound to use 1.0.

Comment: If you're stuck with using old technology then reporting a bug isn't going to help; no-one is going to fix a bug in 12-year old superseded products. You either have to work around the bug, or move forward to newer technology.